# C# - How to watch event queue (windows forms events)

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I have a Windows Forms program that fires lots of events (from an API that  I have no access to its code). I have to do some processing in each event fired, I understand that all events are queued in an "event queue". How can I watch the event queue content? I want to watch all the events queued, only in debug mode, I don't need to do any process with the event queue, just to understand what is really happening when process all events fired by that creepy API. Is there an option for do that in the IDE?

Comment: If you want to understand what happens under the hood, don't use .NET. Program against the WinAPI directly.

Comment: @Eduardo: He wants to understand what happens under the hood of a third-party .Net library.

Comment: Actually that creepy third-party .NET library is not important, I just mentioned because it is the responsible to fired the events. But we can think that events are like an OnClick or an OnChangeXXX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal events are not queued.

You may be talking about Windows messages; if so, use Spy++.

You can also find the functions that raise the events (using Reflector), then add breakpoints to them by clicking Debug, New Breakpoint, Break At Function.

Comment: @Slaks : But he wants the creepy API -- shouldn't he use Evil Spy instead?  (Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spy_vs._Spy)

Comment: Normal events = OnClick, OnKeyUp, etc?
If they are not queued, how all of them are executed, if for example occurs lots of them very quickly (milliseconds between them)?

I'm not sure what Windows Messages are.

Comment: Yes.  Any event that ultimately comes directly from Windows.

Comment: Ok, I think I misunderstood something here. That API that I mentioned has an object that implements some events (that have logic for that object), I supose that events are implemented just like .net framework indicates (public event SomeEvent...) and specifies its own parameters. That events are fired with milliseconds between them, I can see all events get execute, I have read events are queued, so that's why I think this events (from that API) are queued, and in theory all works fine. So, this customized events aren't queued? Then, how this kind of events works really? -Thanks in advance

Comment: They aren't queued; their handlers are raised immediately.  They may be raised in response to a queue; check in Reflector.

Comment: Definitly I read what I wanted to read. In msdn webpage about Application.DoEvents says clearly: "Process all Windows messages currently in the message queue". So, I can use Spy++ like you said. That messages correspond to an event? or why are messages queued and not events directly?

Comment: Messages are a native Win32 concept; events are a .Net concept.